# virtual microphone: File -> Microphone -> Application

Tags: linux, microphone

I need debug my program  and I need something like a virtual 
microphone. I would like device "microphone" where I can put sound file and 
this file will be input for microphone stream. And in application I get this 
stream from this "microphone"

File -> Microphone -> Application

is it possible?

something like bash command should by very very useful:

`aplay --device=mic my_microphone.wav` to run a microphone stream

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks a few details, such as which programming language or which sound server you are using.  Still, I'll give it a try.

I have successfully used the JACK daemon (`jackd`) to debug an audio application.  It might be a bit of work to get `jackd` to work, but it's worth it.  Think of it as a sound server that audio applications and hardware can register audio input and output ports with.  Then you may use `qjackctl` to connect these ports, either manually using *Connect* or **automatically** using the *Patchbay*.

The steps to follow:

- install `jackd` and `qjackctl`
- supposing that you're using ALSA, add a device `jack` to your `~/.asoundrc` so you can output to the jack server (see below)
- start `qjackctl` and from inside, start `jackd` (this might be the time where you run into problems - in my rather complex audio setup, I had to move `pulseaudio` out of the way)
- play your sound file using `aplay --device=jack my_microphone.wav` and try to connect it to your sound card - when you hear something, you're almost done
- create a new JACK input port using the [JACK API](http://jackaudio.org/files/docs/html/group__PortFunctions.html)
- use `jackd`'s *Patchbay* to automatically connect your new input port to a JACK audio output port (which may the output from `aplay`, a media player using JACK (qmmp, VLC and others) or your sound card)

Here's the relevant part of my `~/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.jack
{
        type plug
        slave.pcm "jack_output"
        hint
        {
                show on
                description "Alsa (JACK plugin)"
        }
}

pcm.jack_output
{
        type jack
        playback_ports
        {
                0 system:playback_1
                1 system:playback_2
        }
        capture_ports
        {
                0 system:capture_1
                1 system:capture_2
        }
        hint
        {
                show off
                description "Alsa (JACK output)"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also incorporate *GStreamer* in your application.  See [here](http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/08/28/getting-started-with-gstreamer-with-python/) for a short introduction and [here](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/index.html) for a tutorial.  The element `appsink` might be just what you're looking for.

Here are some command line examples.  There's also an extensive API so you can call all (or part) of this from your application.

Playback pink noise on your default audio output:

```
gst-launch-0.10 audiotestsrc wave=6 ! autoaudiosink
```

Playback an MP3 (or other supported format) on your default audio output:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=my_microphone.mp3 ! decodebin ! \
  audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

*GStreamer is brilliant, so please don't blame me in case you start re-writing your whole application using GStreamer... :)*